# Puppeteer creating a new browser instance on every function call

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

i am trying to create some small functions that someone will be able to glue together in order to have a more reusable code base.

What i am trying to do to create an instance of the browser object in the init.js file. Then pass that browser object in the login.js file and then with the same browser object that i have created i want to navigate to 2 pages that will require login.

I have to following [gist](https://gist.github.com/atragan/48e0a6eec565918df0ad5d636081e29a) with the 3 files mentioned and i have set an example of login into github and then navigating to the "Profile" page and then to the "Projects" page.

```
// init.js
'use strict';
const _driver = require('puppeteer');

module.exports = async () => {
  const _browser = await _driver.launch({
    args: ["--disable-features=site-per-process", "--start-fullscreen"],
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    defaultViewport: null
  });
  return _browser;
};
```

Then I use this on login page,

```
// login.js

'use strict';

const _browser = require('./init.js');
const baseUrl = "https://github.com/login";

let user = {
    username : 'johnDoe',
    password : 'asdzxc123',
};

module.exports = async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await _browser();
        var page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(baseUrl, {waitUntil:'networkidle2'});
        await page.type('#login_field', user.username);
        await page.type('#password', user.password);
        const form = await page.$('input[type=submit]');
        await form.evaluate( form => form.click() );

        await page
        .waitForSelector('.application-main')
        .then(() => {
            return browser;
        });
    }catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

After login, I want to use this same instance on app.js,

```
// app.js
'use strict';

const _browser =  require('./login.js');

viewProfile();
viewProjects();



async function viewProfile(){
    try {
        const browser = await _browser();
        var page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto("https://github.com/settings/profile", {waitUntil:'networkidle2'});
    }catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

async function viewProjects(){
    try {
        const browser = await _browser();
        var page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto("https://github.com/atragan?tab=projects", {waitUntil:'networkidle2'});
    }catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

This is the current structure,

- init.js, is creating a browser instance
- login.js, is calling the init.js
- app.js, is calling login.js

The problem:

I want to pass the same browser instance in all of the modules. Right now it's creating a new instance of the browser on all functions inside app.js file.

Thank you in advance,
Andreas

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: How would you post this? because i am stuck at this for a few days and can't find a way to move forward

Comment: This question is most suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, however when I looked into the code, I saw this could be a nice question if asked in a different way.

Comment: He just didn't ask the correct question. Most probably the correct question is "how to create instance of browser and use it in multiple files?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because you are calling _browser() on login file, which calls _driver.launch() on init.js file. So whenever you are calling the _browser method from login file, you are actually creating a new instance every time.

Here's step by step solution,

## login.js

First, you need to return the browser you are creating here.

Rewrite the following,

```
await page
 .waitForSelector('.application-main')
 .then(() => {
   return browser;
 });
```

to this,

```
await page.waitForSelector('.application-main')
return browser;
```

Now you can use this inside other functions.

## app.js

Create the browser instance before running the viewProfile and viewProjects, then pass the instance inside,

```
const browser = await _browser();
viewProfile(browser);
viewProjects(browser);
```

Remove the browser from inside,

```
async function viewProfile(browser){
    try {
        var page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto("https://github.com/settings/profile", {waitUntil:'networkidle2'});
    }catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

## Possible structures

You can use the class based structure for better readability and maintainability. You can split the functions into files, use the .bind(this) inside constractor, and so on. I will leave that to you.

Here's an example,

```
class MyCrawler{
  init(){
   // the code from init
  }

  login(){
   // the code from login
   // except you use this.browser or this.page instead of _browser;
  }

  viewProfile(){
   // ... same as the login above
  }
}
```

Later you can call it like,

```
const crawler = new MyCrawler()
await crawler.init()
await crawler.login()
await crawler.viewProfile()
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your time, i tried to change my files to reflect the changes you proposed (i have updated the files in the gist as well.) but i get the following error:



const browser = await require('./functions/login.js');
                ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Yes, you need to wrap that inside an async function, or use `.then()`

Comment: For example, async ()=>({ your code })

Comment: Learn more about async await here https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: You should update the code on the answer instead of the gist file. This way the problem stays within SO.